# What other classes do I need?

Tags: java, class

I'm looking to create an application that will be used to help find a suitable University for prospective students to attend (which is based on various criteria about themselves). The application will be used by prospective students to enter details about themselves and a list of Universities will be displayed based on their profile.

I'm on the design stage (class diagram and etc) and i'm currently thinking of some Java classes I need to produce to do this. So far I've only thought of two...

- University class (to hold information about Universities)
- Interface class (this the GUI display)

Can someone help suggest what other class that I will need to create this application? You can suggest as many as you like.

Comment: This will be closed because it's opinion based, but I recommend you not think of it as classes (which are really just abstract behavioral groupings) you need at the outset (what application only uses two classes!?), but rather consider what functionality you need and design from there.

Answer (score 1):

Take every noun in your application description. Make it into a class. See if you can write a more detailed description of your app. Use those nouns as classes as well.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Zak. Never thought of that, i'll give it a go. Have you got any examples?

Comment: your current nouns are student, criteria, profile, details, university... The more detailed your description, the more nouns you will get... For example.. what types of criteria will there be? What will be in a profile?

Comment: the type of criteria I will need will be GCSE grade, current living situation, their personal or parent’s income, degree they’re interested in and so on.